# SonarQube: Suppress warnings on function level?

Tags: warnings, sonarqube

There a way to suppress warning on line-by-line basis (//NOSONAR).

Is there a way to suppress then on function basis (possibly suppressing just a particular type of warning).

Comment: You can deactivate a rule in your quality profile. But can you precise what you are trying to accomplish ? As it might help to answer more specifically to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that on PMD warnings with`@SuppressWarnings`

```
// This will suppress all the PMD warnings in this class
@SuppressWarnings("PMD")
public class Bar {
  void bar() {
    int foo;
  }
}
```

Or you can suppress one rule with an annotation like this:

```
// This will suppress UnusedLocalVariable warnings in this class
@SuppressWarnings("PMD.UnusedLocalVariable")
public class Bar {
  void bar() {
    int foo;
  }
}
```

For further details see: http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.1/suppressing.html